# How to use Decompyle++

Tags: python, c++, decompiling

I am trying to decompile a .pyc python file but when I enter the command to run Decompyle++ (./pydc [path to the pyc file]) or (./pydac [path]) It says unknown command. I have run CMD through the master so the directory is in the correct spot. Do any of yall know how to run it?

The link to the github: https://github.com/zrax/pycdc/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you successfully build it first?  Is `pydac` (or `pydac.exe` on windows) in your current directory?

Comment: @MilesBudnek How do i build it? I am new to this stuff so I am still tryna figure out how everything works.

Comment: That will depend on your OS and toolchain.  It uses cmake, so you'll need to install that and use it to generate the build scripts for your system.  For example, on Linux, you'll need to cd to the directory where you have the source code and run something like `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`.  On Windows you'll either need something like MinGW or to install Visual Studio and generate either a VS solution or nmake makefiles.

Comment: @MilesBudnek can i add you on discord so u can help me out? My discord is Soup#2782

Comment: @MilesBudnek you are a hero! Somehow just cmake . didn't worked for me